# Finding range of a numpy array elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a NumPy array of size 94 x 155:

```
a = [1  2  20  68  210  290..
     2  33 34  55  230  340..
     .. .. ... ... .... .....]
```

I want to calculate the range of each row, so that I get 94 ranges in a result. I tried looking for a `numpy.range` function, which I don't think exists. If this can be done through a loop, that's also fine.

I'm looking for something like `numpy.mean`, which, if we set the axis parameter to 1, returns the mean for each row in the N-dimensional array.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I think `np.ptp` might do what you want:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html

```
r = np.ptp(a,axis=1)
```

where `r` is your range array.

Comment: what does the `axis=1` mean?

Comment: @alvas It means that you want to find the range of a specific dimension independently.  In this case `axis=1` means you want to find the range of each row of your data so it would return a `N` element `numpy` array where `N` is the number of rows.  If `axis=0`, it would find the range of each column independently.  The docs give more details.

Comment: For a version that handles NaN values (aka `nanptp`), see https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/13220. Basically `np.nanmax(a, axis=1) - np.nanmin(a, axis=1)`.

Comment: Make sure to use `axis=foo`. I was trying just `np.ptp(a)` and the single value returned matched what I expected, so I went with that. I was applying this to find the height of detected contours in an image and some were reported as taller than the image itself. I think this occurs if the x location exceeds the height, at which `np.ptp` might be computing something like the total span of all values vs. purely x or y. Still not entirely sure, but wanted to add the note in case anyone else runs into this!

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
def range_of_vals(x, axis=0):
    return np.max(x, axis=axis) - np.min(x, axis=axis)
```

Comment: You should not call your function `range` because there is already a built in function called range.